# How do I program a submit button in a pdf form to ask the user if they want to save first?

Tags: javascript, forms

Building permit applicants in my municipality can go to the website and fill out a pdf form. When they click on the submit form button I want the user to be asked if they want to save it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do that using jQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/ze9Lm9s8/2/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my-form input[type=submit]").on("click", function(e){

    //Make sure it doesn't submit by default
    e.preventDefault();

    //Ask if user would like to save
    var r = confirm("Would you like to save changes?");
        if (r == true) {
            //Do your stuff here
            $("#my-form").submit();
        } else {
            alert('Submission aborted');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="my-form" action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value = "submit"/>
</form>
```

Keep in mind that browser's native confirmation dialog is not reliable so you might want to get a js implementation instead of it.

Comment: Thank you. This works quite well. I've been extremely busy but I do apologize for the delay in answering.

Comment: Glad I could help! Also would really appreciate if you could mark it as the right answer

Comment: Done. Thanks again